# What is the meaning of [:] in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What does the line `del taglist[:]` do in the code below?

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
taglist=list()
url=raw_input("Enter URL: ")
count=int(raw_input("Enter count:"))
position=int(raw_input("Enter position:"))
for i in range(count):
    print "Retrieving:",url
    html=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags=soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        taglist.append(tag)
    url = taglist[position-1].get('href', None)
    del taglist[:]
print "Retrieving:",url
```

The question is "write a Python program that expands on http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/urllinks.py. The program will use urllib to read the HTML from the data files below, extract the href= vaues from the anchor tags, scan for a tag that is in a particular position relative to the first name in the list, follow that link and repeat the process a number of times and report the last name you find". 
Sample problem: Start at http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html 
Find the link at position 3 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 4 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve.
Sequence of names: Fikret Montgomery Mhairade Butchi Anayah 
Last name in sequence: Anayah

Comment: It removes all of the elements from the list.

Comment: @mgilson Can you explain how this program is working i.e last 3 lines?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`[:]` is the array slice syntax for every element in the array.

This answer here goes more in depth of the general uses: [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

```
del arr # Deletes the array itself
del arr[:]  # Deletes all the elements in the array
del arr[2]  # Deletes the third element in the array
del arr[1:]  # etc..
```

Comment: Thanks....also can you explain what this line does "url = taglist[position-1].get('href', None)". i am new to python....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068377/3213282 might help

Comment: I am not getting what "position-1" is doing?

Comment: It's subtracting 1 from "position".

Comment: yes, i know that but why?

Comment: @Sourav Because iterable structures are, like in many (the majority of) programming languages, being indexed from 0, so the first element of the structure has index 0 and the last one has `len(structure) - 1`.