# Python: References, dictionaries and lists

Tags: python

I've just started writing with Python and still getting used with references and where they are and aren't used.

I've written the following code:

```
dummyList = self.getSprayLocation(heading, "left")
self.points['leftLeft'][0] = self.armLocations['leftX'] - self.mmToCoor(dummyList[0])
self.points['leftLeft'][1] = self.armLocations['leftY'] - self.mmToCoor(dummyList[1])
self.points['rightLeft'][0] = self.armLocations['leftX'] + self.mmToCoor(dummyList[0])
self.points['rightLeft'][1] = self.armLocations['leftY'] + self.mmToCoor(dummyList[1])
dummyList = self.getSprayLocation(heading, "mid")
print(self.points['leftLeft'][1])

self.points['leftMid'][0] = self.armLocations['midX'] - self.mmToCoor(dummyList[0])
self.points['leftMid'][1] = self.armLocations['midY'] - self.mmToCoor(dummyList[1])
self.points['rightMid'][0] = self.armLocations['midX'] + self.mmToCoor(dummyList[0])
self.points['rightMid'][1] = self.armLocations['midY'] + self.mmToCoor(dummyList[1])
print(self.points['leftLeft'][1])

dummyList = self.getSprayLocation(heading, "right")
self.points['leftRight'][0] = self.armLocations['rightX'] - self.mmToCoor(dummyList[0])
self.points['leftRight'][1] = self.armLocations['rightY'] - self.mmToCoor(dummyList[1])
self.points['rightRight'][0] = self.armLocations['rightX'] + self.mmToCoor(dummyList[0])
self.points['rightRight'][1] = self.armLocations['rightY'] + self.mmToCoor(dummyList[1])
print(self.points['leftLeft'][1])
```

It's in a Class, where 'points' is a dictionary containing a list:

```
coordinate = [0, 0]
points = {'leftLeft':coordinate, 'rightLeft':coordinate, 'leftMid':coordinate, 'rightMid':coordinate, 'leftRight':coordinate, 'rightRight':coordinate}
```

Note that after every block of code I print the ['leftLeft'][0] value. I expect this value not to change when I don't write to this key in the dictionary.

But when I run this code, this is the output

```
51.861101789
51.8611355556
51.8611192766
```

Which means the value is changed. In fact, all 'leftX' entries are the same and all 'rightX' entries are the same.

Now I think it has something to do with the references, but I haven't come up with a solution for this yet.

Thanks for your help!

---

Edit: 
Thanks to JoshuaF I found that the reference was in the

```
coordinate = [0, 0]
points = {'leftLeft':coordinate, 'rightLeft':coordinate, 'leftMid':coordinate, 'rightMid':coordinate, 'leftRight':coordinate, 'rightRight':coordinate}
```

Block. 'coordinate' was the same 'coordinate' everywhere. The following fixes this:

```
coordinate = [0, 0]
points = {'leftLeft':coordinate[:], 'rightLeft':coordinate[:], 'leftMid':coordinate[:], 'rightMid':coordinate[:], 'leftRight':coordinate[:], 'rightRight':coordinate[:]}
```

I know the [:] has got something to do with references and lists. But what?

---

[meaning of [:] in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241529/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-python)

[Python copy manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Comment: `somelist[:]` creates a shallow copy of `somelist`. It's a shortcut for `somelist[0:len(somelist)]`.

Comment: wrt/ "when references are used", the answer is here:  https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thanks! Very good explanation on that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, every entry in `points` points to the same object, `coordinate`. Changing any of them will change `coordinate` and therefore all the others.

Comment: Right, got it. But how should it be done the python way?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html or a comprehension (i.e. `{'leftleft': [c for c in coordinate]}`).

Comment: And, if you really want to make sure to avoid this error, make `coordinate` a tuple so it's impossible to modify directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dive into tuple's and I'll try to understand them and their behaviour.