# Caesar Cipher shift by two letters

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
def main():

    cc = (input("Enter Message to Encrypt\n"))#user input

    shift = int(2) #shift length

    a=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l",
       "m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"] #reference list

    newa={} #new shifted reference list

    for i in range (0,len(a)):
        newa [a[i]]=a[(i+shift)%len(a)]
        #adds shifted 2 alaphabet into newalaphabet
        #% moodulus used to wrap

        for i in cc: #iterates through cc
            if i in a:
                    a[i]=cc[i]
                    a[i]=newa[i]

main()
```

So I need input from the user #cc

the shift needs to be two

I used an alphabet list

then shift the alphabet by two to create newa

but I do not know how to apply the new alphabet to my user's input

Comment: Can provide the sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the string `cc` and replace all the alphabets using the `get` method of `newa`. Characters that are not in the dictionary are left as is, by passing them as the default to `newa.get` when the key is missing:

```
newa = {}
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    newa[x] = a[(i+shift) % len(a)]

encrypted_text = ''.join(newa.get(i, i) for i in cc)
```

Python's builtin [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) can be used in place of `range(len(a))` in this case where you need the items in `a` and their respective indices.

Comment: why do you need the (i,i) in the new.get ?

Comment: That's an alternative way of *getting* a value from a dictionary which will not raise a `KeyError` when the key is not found. Read [Understanding `.get()` method in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068349/understanding-get-method-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use mapping for every char, then join them back to create the encrypted message:

```
''.join(map(lambda x: chr((ord(x) - 97 + shift) % 26 + 97) if x in alphabet else x, cc.lower()))
```

Integrate it like that:

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
cc = input('Enter string to encode: ')
shift = 2 # could be any number

encrypted = ''.join(map(lambda x: chr((ord(x) - 97 + shift) % 26 + 97) if x in alphabet else x, cc.lower()))
```

`cc.lower()` for the letters to be all same case (to map using constant `ord`)

`chr((ord(x) - 97 + shift) % 26 + 97)` :

- get the value of the number minus 97 (0 for `a`, 1 for `b`, etc.).
- apply the shift (`a` turns to `c`, etc.).
- modulate by 26 to prevent letters like `z` from exceeding (25 + 2 = 27, 27 % 26 = 1 = `b`).
- add 97 to bring the letter back to ascii standard (97 for `a`, 98 for `b`, etc.)

`if x in alphabet else x` cover for signs that are not letter (if you want to ignore spaces and punctuation use `if x in alphabet else ''` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to map inputs to outputs

```
shifted_a = a[-shift:] + a[:-shift]
cipher = {a[i]: shifted_a[i] for i in range(len(a))}
output = ''.join(cipher[char] for char in cc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just build transition table and use it to decode string.

```
import string
shift = 2
letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
transtable = str.maketrans({letters[i]: letters[(i + shift) % len(letters)] 
                            for i in range(len(letters))})

cc = input('Enter string to encode: ')
print(cc.translate(transtable))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my solution in there. It should be pretty clear how it works...

```
import string

index_lookup = {letter: index for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}

def caesar_letter(l, shift=2):
    new_index = index_lookup[l] + shift
    return string.ascii_lowercase[new_index % len(index_lookup)]

def caesar_word(s):
    return ''.join([caesar_letter(letter) for letter in s])
```

I think the above is better for readability but if you're opposed to imports...

```
index_lookup = {chr(idx): idx - ord('a') for idx in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)}
```

...

```
In [5]: caesar_word('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
Out[5]: 'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab'
```