# Python: How does converters work in genfromtxt() function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am new to Python, I have a following example that I don't understand

The following is a csv file with some data

```
%%writefile wood.csv
item,material,number
100,oak,33
110,maple,14
120,oak,7
145,birch,3
```

Then, the example tries to define a function to convert those trees name above to integers.

```
tree_to_int = dict(oak = 1,
                   maple=2,
                   birch=3)

def convert(s):
    return tree_to_int.get(s, 0)
```

The first question is why is there a "0" after "s"? I removed that "0" and get same result.

The last step is to read those data by numpy.array

```
data = np.genfromtxt('wood.csv',
                     delimiter=',', 
                     dtype=np.int, 
                     names=True,   
                     converters={1:convert}
                    )
```

I was wondering for the converters argument, what does {1:convert} exact mean? Especially what does number 1 mean in this case?

Comment: For your first question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068349/understanding-get-method-in-python

Comment: Also see the Python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict; scroll down to see the description of the [`get` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Okay, that documentation is pretty straightforward. Would you mind answering my second question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, according to the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), `{1:convert}` is a dictionary whose keys are column numbers (where the first column is column 0) and whose values are functions that convert the entries in that column.

So in this code, the 1 indicates column one of the csv file, the one with the names of the trees. Including this argument causes numpy to use the `convert` function to replace the tree names with their corresponding numbers in `data`.