# What is the use of ,0 in this function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
stock = {'football': 4, 'boardgame': 10, 'leggos': 100, 'doll': 5}    
def fillable(stock, merch, n):
      return stock.get(merch, 0) >= n

print(fillable(stock, 'leggos', 10))
```

The result in codewars:

> Traceback:    in     in fillable TypeError: unorderable types:
>   NoneType() >= int()

Comment: Presumably `merch` is a `dict` so it's calling `.get` and passing a default value if the key doesn't exist but who knows because you posted an incomplete example

Comment: Allow me to answer with a question: what does `stock`'s `get` method do?

Comment: The code you've shown us is probably fine. Somehow `stock[merch]` is `None`. Inspect places where values are inserted, e.g. `stock[merch] = x` (where `x` may turn out to have the value `None`).

Comment: It looks like `stock` is supposed to be a dictionary containing only integer values, but someone stored `None` at key `merch`.  `stock.get(merch, 0)` would return zero when key `merch` is missing, but it won't protect you against bad data in the dictionary.

Comment: The code you've given works fine. Presumably codewars calls `fillable` with its own `stock` value that contains `None`. Include the question definition here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the syntax for get() method −

```
dict.get(key, default = None)
Parameters
```

key − This is the Key to be searched in the dictionary.

default − This is the Value to be returned in case key does not exist.

see more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming n is int() in this case, try converting stock.get(merch, 0) to int before comparing it.

To answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068377/2774199

Comment: This likely won't work. The OP somehow has `None` stored against one of their keys (unlike in the sample given) and trying to cast that to not will throw an error.