# Discord.py logging edited and deleted messages in a specific channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to have a discord bot for my server that logs deleted messages in a specific channel. I have tried but I'm new to coding this is what I came up with and it doesn't work. The code is shown below:

```
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="{} deleted a message".format(member.name.message), description="", color="teal")
    embed.add_field(name= message.content ,value="Deleted message", inline=True)
    channel=bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and the correct code please, it would be greatly appreciated and how to do logging for edited messages too

Comment: Well, what does not work? Be more specific please and maybe add a traceback if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at what's expected of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not only do we not know what incorrect result you're currently getting, we can't test your code without writing the rest of it ourselves.

Comment: It says "NameError: name 'member' is not defined" @Dominik

Comment: Well, look at your code. You're trying to access `member.name.message`, but you haven't defined `member`. (Note that this still isn't a reproducible example and you haven't shown the full stack trace, so there may be other issues, but we have no way of knowing.)

Comment: How do i define "member" @CrazyChucky

Comment: For the purposes of this site, you should start by reading [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), if you haven't already. Then edit your question so that you provide one. We don't necessarily need your entire *actual* code, but we do need a self-contained, runnable "test case", if you will, that generates the same problem you're having. And a full stack trace (the "in line __" stuff), not just the error message.

Comment: (Note: one exception to the usual rule that the provided code should be complete, such that we can copy and paste it and run it as-is, is that you *should not* include your Discord bot's unique token.) Here's a decent [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453633/how-to-snipe-messages-from-a-specific-channel-discord-py) of what a "complete" (testable) Discord bot MRE looks like. (There's no stack trace because they weren't getting a exception, just incorrect behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="{}'s message deleted.".format(message.author.name), #message.author is sender of the message
        description=message.content,
        color="teal"
    )
    channel=bot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Add `@bot.event` above of the code if you didn't.

Comment: i did and it still doesnt work, do i need to download a codebase or something?